# Not able to find the property of an object in Angular9

Tags: json, mean-stack, registration, angular9

I'm doing a full-stack project where I got an Object with two property "success" and "message", through API when I register the form.

But my Frontend which is in Angular is not being able to read the success property.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authService.registerUser` returns an `Observable`, that's why you can `subscribe` to it. You should check, if the object passed in the returned `Observable` corresponds to the expected object (the one that contains the properties "success" and "message").

If this is the case, you could try to access the property in the following way:

```
if (!data['success']) {
  this.submitting = false
}
```

Otherwise you have to correct the code in order to handle the `data` according to its type.

Comment: yes, it returns observable and it worked.  thanks <3